# How to pass dataGrid1.CurrentCell (or it's content) to a Converter bind to dataGrid2.CellStyle as a parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'd like to know if it is possible to pass datagrid.CurrentCell (or it's Content or the dataGrid itself) as ConverterParameter to a converter bound to a another datagrid. I'm trying to highligth the cells of the second dg containing one of the values contained in the Selected(Current) Cell of the first one. So far i managed to gain access to the cells of the second datagrid by binding it's CellStyle (RelativeSource Self) property to the said converter.

Update: As suggested by nit's post, i did as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:currentValsHLM x:Key="cellColorConverter" />...

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cellColorConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding Path="Row" /><!--Neeeded because previous bind datacell Content will be always (friggin) null -->
                                <!-- Here i would like to bind to datagrid1 holding the data to compare in the converter -->
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cellColorConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding Path="Row" />
                                <!-- Same as above -->
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The MultiBinding.Bindings section misses the data ((string)dataGrid1.CurrentCell.Content, i guess) the converter should know about to choose which cells needs to be highlighted and which don't. Is there a way to obtain such data?

Update 2: And.... did it! The (ok, stupid) answer was `<Binding ElementName="dataGrid1" />`. With CurrentItem[CurrentColumn.Header] i finally can hold (and squeeze) the data i need. Hurray to me!

Note: It's unbelievable! Until now the first binding did provide a reference to the current DataGridCell of datagrid2 the Content of which was always null (so unuseful), so i needed the second bind to access the real data. Now, point blank, WPF (codename BTCH) sends to the converter objects filled with actual values (real ones). Now i understand all the posts saying "Why on my friend system xaml was working while it's not on mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConverterParameter does not support Binding. Try using MultiBinding to bind to properties you want (SelectedItem of grid, or Current cell content of grid) and use IMultiValueConverter to multibind the properties

Comment: I know. My idea was more or less to reference the first datagrid CurrentItem as window resource (if possible) and then pass (said another way binding to) that reference as parameter for the converter. Another dead end. I'll try the MultiBinding thing.